# Check calculation of mean value of a vector field over a sphere

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, integration

Let $E=-\nabla(\Phi)$ be a vector field, where $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that the mean value
$$\bar E:=\frac{-1}{V_{\text{sphere}}}\int_{V{\text{sphere}}}\nabla \Phi = \frac{-1}{V_{\text{sphere}}}\int_{S{\text{sphere}}}\Phi \vec{n} \,dS$$
of this field will only have a component in the $\phi$ direction but not in the $r$ or $\theta$ one, if $\Phi(r,\theta)$ does not depend on $\phi$?

Because in that case I calculated that for $S$, where $S$ is the surface of a sphere $\int_{S} \Phi(r,\theta) \vec{n} \, dS$ is zero in the first two components?

Since there are not so many answers, I will try to be more precise. The integral I am talking about gives me:
\begin{multline}\frac{1}{V_{\text{sphere}}}\int_{S{\text{sphere}}}\Phi(r,\theta) (\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), \cos(\theta))^T \, dS =\\
 \frac{1}{V_{\text{sphere}}}\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} \\ \Phi(r,\theta)(\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), \cos(\theta))^T r^2\sin(\theta) \, d\phi \,d\theta.
\end{multline}
Now this is zero in the first two components since $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\phi) \ d\phi=0$ and the same for $\cos(\phi)$and I was wondering whether this can be true?

Comment: Mean over what?

Comment: the mean value over the sphere

Comment: Mean= flux through the sphere?

Comment: I gave you my definition in the excercise, hopefully it helps you

Comment: $\nabla$ is written `\nabla`. $\sin$ and $\cos$ are written `\sin` and `\cos`. There should be a small space `\,` before a differential $d\theta$ to separate it a bit.

Comment: corrected it, sorry

Comment: What is the purpose of the $\vec n$ in the definition of the integral?

Comment: It is the unit vector that points outwards from the sphere in order to get the surface integral. You might want to have a look at the third corollary here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Corollaries

Comment: Probably in your integrals you should replace $\Phi$ with $\nabla \Phi$: you are computing the "mean value of" the flux of $E$ through $S$.

Comment: No, I am calculating the mean value of the electric field in the volume.

Comment: no, I want to get a mean value of the vector field in there, so if I had there a dot product I would not get the mean value of a VECTOR field

Comment: Ok, now it is in the volume :(. But in this case I agree with @Chris Culter: I do not get the purpose of the normal vector in the 3 integrals...

Comment: did you take a look at the third corollary in the link I posted there?

Comment: yes, and it is not what you write above. Your notation mixes $S$ as  a sphere (first relation), $S$ as surface of the sphere (paragraph below) etc...

Comment: maybe you could write down the integral that would give me in your opinion the mean value of the vector field $E$ in the volume, so that I better understand what you mean

Comment: Your $\bar E$ is an integrated quantity, not associated with a particular position.  How can you ask if it has a $\hat\phi$ component when the position at which the basis should be computed is not defined?

Comment: $\bar{E}$ is supposed to be a vector, namely the mean value of all $E$ vectors inside of the sphere and since it is a vector it seems to me that it is a valid question talking about its $\hat \phi $ component

Comment: My point is that $\hat \phi$ points in different directions depending on *where* you're located in space. What would $\bar E = \hat \phi$ even mean?  Tangential to some sphere, but *where* on the sphere?

Comment: That would mean that at each point on the sphere the direction of the field would be in the direction that this vector $\hat \phi$ points.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If you converted it back to Cartesian bases, you would have fundamentally different vectors at every point.  Integrating is going to give you a single vector. When you're done with the integration, you're going to get a vector that has no position dependence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made correct observations except that your logic shows that $\bar E$ is in the $\hat z$ direction, not the $\hat \phi$ direction.  You expanded the unit vector $\hat n$ in terms of Cartesian basis vectors $\hat x, \hat y, \hat z$, describing each component with spherical coordinates.  The basis is still nevertheless Cartesian.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT*** No answer: I fix notation to try to understand the OP question.

The   [divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Corollaries) roughly states that "... the outward flux of a vector field $E$ through a closed surface $S$ is equal to the volume integral of the divergence $\nabla cdot E$ over the region $V$ inside the surface". In formulae:

$$\int_V \nabla\cdot E d\mu=\int_S E\cdot n d\sigma. $$

The divergence $\nabla\cdot E$ of a vector field $E$ is a function given by

$$\nabla\cdot E=\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial E}{\partial x_i}. $$

In the flux integral the integrand is given by the function $E\cdot n$, denoting by $n$ the outward normal vector to the surface $S$.

- OP question

The integral  $\bar{E}:=\frac{-1}{V_{sphere}}\int_{V_{sphere}}\nabla\Phi$ is not well defined, as one integrates a vector (i.e. $\nabla\Phi$) over the region $V$. The equality

$$\frac{-1}{V_{sphere}}\int_{V_{sphere}}\nabla\Phi=\frac{-1}{V_{sphere}}\int_{S}\Phi n dS$$

seems t reproduce the divergence theorem, with notation issues as noted above. $\Phi n$ cannot be the scalar product between vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ as $\Phi$ is a function.

Hint: I suggest to try to fix notation and use the divergence theorem. In that case one needs to understand the formula for

$$\nabla \cdot E=\nabla\cdot(\nabla \Phi). $$

Comment: I want to calculate the mean value of the vector field E in a sphere. Just to clarify what I mean: E is a vector field that gives me at each place in this sphere a vector and I want to get the mean value of all those vectors inside the sphere.

Comment: Ok, but my problem is to understand in which sense you would like to compute the "mean". If you take the definition of the mean of a function straightforwardly, you would arrive at the mean of the components of the vector field $E$. Is this what you want?

Comment: In the sence of this article here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0002021.pdf

Comment: Avitus, there's nothing inherently wrong with integrating a vector over a volume.  Not sure why you're trying to fix anything.  It's clear that $\Phi n$ is the product of a scalar field $\Phi$ and a unit vector $n$.  That's well-defined.

Comment: @Muphrid my problem is that I do not understand what the OP wants (in particular with the concept of mean of a vector field over a region): I will check the paper he refers to. In my answer-not answer I wanted to point out that the use of the divergence theorem was not correct. Integrating a vector component-wise is fine to me, but it is another computation.

Comment: When you find the mean value of a function in an interval (1d), you integrate the function and then divide by the length of the interval.  This is the same concept, except applied to a vector field and a volume.  The theorem the OP is using is a known corollary of the divergence theorem--a form of the Generalized Stokes theorem or the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: ok, now I got it: the integral is componentwise :) In summary, @Lipschitz you are not trzing to use the divergence theorem but rather its corollary componentwise. Am I right? Formula (1) in the reference makes sense, now

Comment: Thanks to @Muphrid as well for the discussion

Comment: But is my calculation correct them?

Comment: The computation is correct: the mean $\bar{E}$ is of the form $\bar{E}=(0,0,...)$, where the components of $\bar{E}$ are w.r.t. the coordinate axis, and not the directions determined by $r,\theta$ and $\phi$. So $\bar{E}$ points in the $z$-direction, in general.